# SELECT on 80 Million rows taking too long

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-performance

**Table:**

```
                       Table "public.hugetable"
 Column  |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
---------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 reqid   | character varying(15) |           | extended | 
 browser | character varying(15) |           | extended | 
 a       | smallint              |           | plain    | 
 b       | smallint              |           | plain    | 
 metarr  | smallint[]            |           | extended |
```

Number of Rows: 80 million

Indexes: None

**Explain:**

```
testdb=> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) select b from hugetable;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on hugetable  (cost=0.00..6514286.08 rows=80000008 width=2) (actual time=0.009..598004.456 rows=80000000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=472831 read=5241455
 Total runtime: 674134.766 ms
```

`metarr smallint[]` contains 250 elements.

Query takes a similar amount of time with `select b from hugetable where a=someval` or `select metric[199] from hugetable`

**Server specs:**

```
db.m3.xlarge
Type:Type   Standard - Current Generation
vCPU:Number of virtual cores    4 vCPU
Memory: 15 GiB
```

---

I've never worked with such a large dataset so I'm **not sure if 10 minutes is normal** for this kind of Query.

In practice, there will be another column (datetime). The table will contain ~80 million records over 1 full day, and queries will always be as `SELECT metarr[someindex] from hugetable where datetimecolumn > something and datetimecolumn <something`.

What can I do to make this faster? It seems that once I add a datetime column and query for a period of time, it will still take an immense amount of time!

Comment: Indexing the table will go a long way to getting your query times down.

Comment: Indexing a table on what? And is 600 seconds a reasonable time *without* indexing?

Comment: Your query is asking for all data, so that's what you get. And then it's up to the performance of your system how fast this can be done.

Comment: Considering $$ isn't an issue, what specific attribute would I need to increase in order to get better performance for something like this? IOPS? http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

Comment: @danmullen  Nonsense - the fastest way to fetch a full table's contents is almost always a seqscan, so the example given here won't benefit from an index at all. You're right that the "in practice..." part would benefit from a btree index on `datetimecolumn` though.

Comment: As written this is all about sequential read performance. EBS provisioned iops will help, but cost $lots. Seriously lots. The biggest improvement you can make for this sort of thing is to get off AWS EC2 and onto something with good storage. Or use something like a high I/O instance's instance store and rely on replication and failover for recovery if it crashes and you lose the instance store contents.

Comment: BTW, what's the output of `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('hugetable')), pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('hugetable'));` ?

Comment: To be fair @Craig Ringer, I was referring to day-to-day performance when accessing this table.

Answer (score 0):

The table on disk is bigger than your RAM. Therefore, the table cannot be fully cached in RAM. Increase RAM size to fit your working set. This will remove all IO.

Index just the columns you need. That way PostgreSQL can perform an index-only scan and scan much less data. This reduces the working set.

You might now be bottlenecked on the network between the DB and the app.

Answer (score 0):

**How to increase database query performance**

1. Index the column that is being used for comparisons (ex: date column should be indexed in both examples)

   ```
   SELECT * FROM X WHERE X.date = 2014
   ```

   or

   ```
   SELECT * FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON X.date = Y.date
   ```
2. horizontal partition (shard) the table to several blocks (ex: daily rotation) and put each block on different machine.
3. replicate the database by duplicating the db partition across multiple machines. this wont help much in your case unless you have concurrent queries with different criterias
4. use high IOPS SSD drives (AWS call them provisioned IO).
5. for dates use datetime type it has better performance than int
   http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/
6. use memcached, redis, ..etc to cache the results for a faster retrieval (if the same query will run more than once)